# How to select first 10 files out of 47 from ADLS using ADF pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have 47 files in ADLS folder. I need to batch process it. Every iteration should process 10 files. So it should have 5 iteration with 10 files for each iteration and last iteration with 47 files. I need to implement this logic in ADF pipeline

I tried to filter using the filter activity but not able to filter based on the number of files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To files with the batches, you need to use multiple activities or increment variables to get the batch of 10 file names.

Follow below steps to achieve your requirements:

- First take get meta data to get the list of files from the folder:
  [image]
- Then take Foreach activity and pass the output of get metadata to foreach activity:
  [image]
- Then under for each activity take append variable to store all file names in one array:
  [image]
- After this create two variables with name **skip** and **skipinc** type integer and default value as 0
  [image]
- Now take until activity and set the expression as `@equals(variables('skipinc'), 50)`
  [image]
- Under until activity take set variable add variable skip which we created earlier and set the value as `@variables('skipinc')`
  [image]
- Then take another set variable to create batches of files using expression `@take(skip(variables('files'),variables('skip')),add(variables('skip'),10))`
  [image]

> **Note**: After this step you can take execute pipeline and pass ths variable to that pipeline and process that batch of files

- Then take another set variable to increment the skip value with `@add(variables('skip'),10 )`.
  [image]

**Output:**

**For every iteration of until loop it will create a batch of 10 files:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! Does your flow also work for different number of total files in the adls folder?

Comment: yes, it will work for different number of total files in the adls folder.